# javascript getElementsByClassName("foo"||"bar")

Tags: javascript, dom

Basically I want a snippet of javascript to add the height of the browser window to any elements with *either* of the classes `fullscreen` or `fullheight`

```
function fullsize(){
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen"),
        b = document.getElementsByClassName("fullheight");
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        a[i].style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
    }
    for (var j=0; j<b.length; j++){
        b[j].style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", fullsize),
window.addEventListener("resize", fullsize);
```

This (above) works perfectly well, I was just wondering if there was any way to condense it into just one `for(){...}` like the jQuery equiv.

```
function fullsizes(){
    $(".fullheight,.fullscreen").each(function(){
      $(this).height($(window).height())
    })
}
```

Comment: Note that your code does not test for the mutual exclusion. In jquery syntax that would be `$('.fullheight:not(.fullscreen), .fullscreen:not(.fullheight)')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

*Code example*

```
document.querySelectorAll(".fullscreen, .fullheight");
```

*Change your to code*

```
function fullsize(){
    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".fullscreen, .fullheight"); 
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        a[i].style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use javascript instead of writing some css

style.css:

```
.fullscreen, .fullheight {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

You can use document.querySelectorAll like Satpal said.

Comment: This is certainly the future, but, as of now ```querySelector``` has much better support than ```Viewport units```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) to do this:

> `querySelector`
>
> Returns the first matching Element node within the node's subtree. If no matching node is found, null is returned.
>
> `querySelectorAll`
>
> Returns a NodeList containing all matching Element nodes within the node's subtree, or an empty NodeList if no matches are found.

You might also find the following website useful; it contains examples of how you can do jQuery-like things without using jQuery: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can merge arrays with the `concat` method

```
var c = a.concat(b)
```

And then you can iterate over `c` instead.